# $_POST[ ] and mysql_fetch_arrays together

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I'm working on outputting data from two different sources into an HTML table. One source is a `mysql_fetch_array`, the other is a `$_POST` array. There are three `<td>` tables from mysql and one from `$_POST` outputting via a while loop. To associate the arrays on the output page, I planned to store the `$_POST` data in the table via the row id and then query the whole row further down the page.

The issue I have is that I can't seem to get the `$_POST` array values UPDATED into the row correctly. The last value in the `$_POST` array is all what's stored in all selected fields.

The input page arrays are captured with `id [ ]` and `unit_ass[ ]` and are passed to the output page.

The output page code:

```
require_once ("../includes/db_connect.inc");

    $pid = array_filter($_POST['id']);
    $gid = implode(",", $pid);

    $sua = array_filter($_POST['unit_ass']);

    foreach($sua as $value) echo $value . "<br>"; // this outputs correct values in the correct order.

    foreach($sua as $value) mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET unit_ass='$value' WHERE id IN ( $gid )");
```

Just stripping empty keys with `array_filter()` ... When I echo the values in the first foreach statement, they are displayed correctly and in correct order.

However, only the last value from the `$sua` array is updating the table rows as determined by $gid. The foreach isn't iterating the array values and performing the UPDATE as it should. The data via `id[ ]` is displayed correctly further down the page via a `mysql_fetch-array` in a while loop.

I've been staring at this for several hours now and can't seem to find the solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you want to update value `unit_ass` of each row whose id is in `$gid` to corresponding value in `$sua`?

Comment: If this is your complete code sample, then you need to define `$tbl_name`.

Comment: All of the database connection stuff along with $tbl_name is contained in the require_once file at the top.

Comment: FYI, you're susceptible to an SQL injection attack with this query, and should look at escaping `$value`.

Comment: Hafichuk - thanks. Yeah... Once I get this working the way I want, I'll clean it up.

Comment: Just so were clear, you're SQL is updating *each* row listed in `$gid` *every time*. If you're intent it so update a single row (instead of all of them), then you need to change your where clause.

Comment: Ooooh. That's probably it. That's why all rows are being updated with the last value. I didn't even see that. I'll have to rethink that.

Comment: check my updated answer... It will solve all your problem...

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($sua as $key => $value){
    $value = mysql_escape_string($value);
    $id = mysql_escape_string ($pid[$key]);
    mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET unit_ass='$value' WHERE id='$id'");
}
```

Comment: Yes it is. I'm solving the logic error raised by the question. Escaping can be done outside of this code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe `$gid = implode(",", $pid);` will give one value (consider as `1`)

Now suppose `$sua = array_filter($_POST['unit_ass']);` give you `ABC, PQR, LMN`.

so your query will be executed like this

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET unit_ass='ABC' WHERE id='1'");
 mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET unit_ass='PQR' WHERE id='1'");
 mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET unit_ass='LMN' WHERE id='1'");
```

as your `$gid` is same through-out, you are seeing Only last update... Hope you got your mistake...

I believe you also want to change `gid`. For that check @Bao Nhan answer, that might help you as well!!!

**Update :**

Use below code... It will work now...

```
require_once ("../includes/db_connect.inc");

$sua = array_filter($_POST['unit_ass']);

 foreach($sua as $myKey => $value) {
     $myID = $pid[$myKey];
     mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET unit_ass='$value' WHERE id='$myID'");
 }
```

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Actually `implode(",", $pid);` returns a string of comma separated values containing the ids of the selected rows from the input page.

Comment: Use this `foreach($sua as $value) echo gid` and let me know what you get... This will solve my problem. If you are getting `1, 2, 3` then problem is solved.

Comment: @Charlie Somerville : What is best way then?? Could you please let us know??? Else you ONLY know to VOTE DOWN???

Comment: Sorry, I had to take off for awhile. Back now.

Comment: I didn't try this code. But each array returns the selected ids and unit_ass from the input page. because of the `array_filter` stripping the empty keys and values, the `$_POST` array may look like `[22]=>unit_ass value, [15]=>unit_ass value`.

The id array may look like `[2]=>1, [34]=>3. The arrays are constructed from two different sources and therefore have different keys. Is there a way to reset the keys so the resulting array_filter keys match?

Comment: can you try updated code and let me know what you are getting?